# Remove N consecutive repeated characters in a string

Tags: python, string, iteration

I am trying to solve a problem where the user inputs a string say str = "aaabbcc" and an integer n = 2.

So the function is supposed to remove characters that appearing 'n' times from the str and output only "aaa".

I tried couple of approaches and I'm not able to obtain the right output. 
Are there any Regular expression functions that I could use or any recursive functions or just plain old iterations.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `itertools.groupby`

**Ex:**

```
from itertools import groupby    
s = "aaabbcc"
n = 2

result = ""
for k, v in groupby(s):
    value = list(v)
    if not len(value) == n:
        result += "".join(value)
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
aaa
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from collections import Counter

counts = Counter(string)
string = "".join(c for c in string if counts[c] != 2)
```

Edit: Wait, sorry, I missed "consecutive". This will remove characters that occur exactly two times in the whole string (fitting your example, but not the general case).

Consecutive filter is a bit more complex, but doable - just find the consecutive runs first, then filter out the ones which have length two.

```
runs = [[string[0], 0]]
for c in string:
    if c == runs[-1][0]:
        runs[-1][1] += 1
    else:
        runs.append([c, 1])
string = "".join(c*length for c,length in runs if length != 2)
```

Edit2: As the other answers correctly point out, the first part of this is done natively by `groupby`

```
from itertools import groupby

string = "".join(c*length for c,length in groupby(string) if length != 2)
```

Comment: This solution works as well but  I found it a bit hard to understand the 1st edit. Thanks for your approach!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
>>> s = "aaabbccddddddddddeeeee"
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> n = 3
>>> groups = (list(values) for _, values in groupby(s))
>>> "".join("".join(v) for v in groups if len(v) < n)
'bbcc'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [15]: some_string = 'aaabbcc'

In [16]: n = 2

In [17]: final_string = ''

In [18]: for k, v in Counter(some_string).items():
    ...:     if v != n:
    ...:         final_string += k * v
    ...:

In [19]: final_string
Out[19]: 'aaa'
```

You'll need: `from collections import Counter`

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import defaultdict
def fun(string,n):
    dic = defaultdict(int)
    for i in string:
        dic[i]+=1
    check = []
    for i in dic:
        if dic[i]==n:
            check.append(i)
    for i in check:
        del dic[i]
    return dic
string = "aaabbcc"
n = 2
result = fun(string, n)
sol =''
for i in result:
    sol+=i*result[i]

print(sol)
```

output

```
aaa
```